# How to get invitable friends from facebook with deprecated api?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an game for android which uses facebook to keep track of user to save his game state in the cloud. We want to allow the user to invite his friends from facebook. However the facebook graph api no longer supports to get invitable friends (since April 4th https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends/)

I can't find in page any information about how to workaround it. Is that it? No more ways to invite friends?

Comment: There is no workaround. Haven't you been watching the news? FB has tightened a lot of access recently due to those issues.

Comment: Why would they remove it if there was a way to work around it? And if it was just deprecated to be replaced with something else the documentation would of course list the new way of doing it

Comment: I've watched some memes on internet about it. But maybe they could provide some safer way to supply those informations. Maybe allowing the user to select friends to invite in FB page (redirected from the app).

Comment: i don´t think that´s necessary. if people really want to invite friends, they could just send them a message, for example. there is no reason to build workarounds for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have written an article on this subject, [read here](https://blog.getsocial.im/deprecation-of-facebook-invitable-friends-graph-api-and-its-impact-on-organic-growth/).

If you have a gaming app you can still use the GameRequest dialog. [Facebook App invites was also deprecated back in Feb](https://blog.getsocial.im/facebook-deprecates-app-invites-are-you-ready/#acquisition). However, our data has shown that organic installs through Facebook are only 1% when compared to other channels like WhatsApp (see a [study by Sega and GetSocial](http://www.pocketgamer.biz/infographic/67748/sega-and-getsocial-study-on-viral-ua/)).

Disclaimer: I am the founder of [GetSocial](https://www.getsocial.im)

Answer (score 0):

Currently no work arounds.

> Returns Empty Set — The following nodes and edges will now only return
>   empty data sets:
>
> - /user/invitable_friends

Breaking Changes : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#games-4-4